# my react firebase custom domain title and description doesnt change

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have my react website hosted on firebase with custom domain, the domain is added to google search console/google webmaster, the problem is the title and description of website does not change when i search my website on google.com.it keeps showing old title and description.i have tried react helmet, react meta tags, browser clear history, even tried with simple html file deployment, the title and description does not change.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to ask google to recrawl the website if you would like it changed quicker than it would take google to revist the site organically. There are details on how to do this here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl

Ultimately you'll need to Inspect the URL using the URL Inspection tool. Details on how to do this are in the link above.